# Tensorflow installed can't be imported

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to import `tensorflow`. But even after installing it, it doesn't seem to be recognized.

```
    >conda create -n tf tensorflow
    >conda activate tf
(tf)>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.15 --user
...
Successfully installed absl-py-0.9.0 astor-0.8.1 gast-0.2.2 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.28.1 h5py-2.10.0 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 markdown-3.2.1 numpy-1.18.2 opt-einsum-3.2.0 protobuf-3.11.3 setuptools-46.1.3 six-1.14.0 tensorboard-1.15.0 tensorflow-1.15.0 tensorflow-estimator-1.15.1 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-1.0.1 wheel-0.34.2 wrapt-1.12.1

(tf) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\covent_garden_ds>python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Python3 is there:

```
(tf) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Covent Garden\covent_garden_ds>where python3
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

It's not the one I should be using, isn't it?

Comment: Can you put the output of `where python3` as well as `pip --version`. Probably using Python and pip versions that aren't linked

Comment: @awarrier99 I think you are right ...

Comment: yeah, so it's not seeing your installed module. What's the output of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you running? In order to both successfully import and run the Tensorflow module, you **must** have the 64 bit version of Python installed. If you are using the latest version of Python, which to the best of my knowledge is 3.8.2, completely uninstall that version of Python, and downgrade to the latest Python version with 64 bit support.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the output of `pip --version` to find where your anaconda files are located, you can find the anaconda python executable, usually about two directory levels higher (if `pip` is in `C:\example\anaconda\lib\site-packages`, then python is probably in `C:\example\anaconda`) and use a full path to that python executable to run the file like `C:\example\anaconda\python app.py`. Or you could update your path environment variable to replace `C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` with the directory containing the anaconda python executable

I've had this same exact issue (but on macOS) several times before I realized what was wrong, and I've seen several others have this issue too. I wish there was a way Python could somehow better regulate this to make sure the default executables for `pip` and `python` are always in sync